# How to use React ScrollArea plugin using React Classes?

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, gulp, reactjs

**Finally** I found exactly the kind of scroll bars I wanted for my React App: the nice-scroll-bars, but after a day of wrestling this plugin, I cannot understand their example: The flow of creating a scroll able component goes like this:

jsx React Component + render method with extra CSS baked in to it ===gulp compiling=====> a new main.js component that is scroll-able.

I setup 3 similar React Scroll bars examples from Github today. The instructions seemed just as simple as the others.

Here is the repo:

https://github.com/souhe/reactScrollbar

**Here's the very simple set up instructions**

1) Installing with npm: npm install react-scrollbar --save

2) Wrapping the content that you want to scroll like so:

```
var React = require('react');
var ScrollArea = require('react-scrollbar');


var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollArea
        speed={0.8}
        className="area"
        contentClassName="content"
        horizontal={false}
        >
        Some long content.
      </ScrollArea>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<App/>, document.body);
```

3) Adding a .CSS file(scrollbar.css) to the project: 
  (this file is in the example once you install it)

**The Problem For The Simple Minded Folk**

**What I see and think:**

"Oh I need a  component. I can just install it from npm and then require it to use like any other React component.Any extra CSS is linked in the index.html file."

**What the example makes the process look like:**

It looks like I'm wrapping up an ES6 React component with another js file and also pouring in extra CSS in the JavaScript in order to make a pre-compiled scroll-able component.

I'm not sure if this plugin is confusing because:

- These scroll bars are for the new ES6 wave of doing things and the
  addition of using classes in React.
- The author has bundle up the code his own way just for a quick example.
- There is just a lot of fancy ".jsx" and ".less" trans-compiling going  on that is confusing a simple plugin illustration.

**Here are the sticking Points for a Noob:**

1) Why does it seem we are pre-compiling the component? 
gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task("webpack", function() {
    return gulp.src('./examples/**/js/main.js')
        .pipe(webpack( webpackConf ))
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../'))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

2)Are we baking in extra CSS here? Why not just link it in the html?

main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './app.jsx';

var css = require("style!css!../../../dist/css/scrollbar.css");

React.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.getElementById("main"));
```

3) Where did this ScrollArea.js file come from?? Is this just the scrolling module being added in manually so that we don't have to install it from npm?
app.jsx

```
import ScrollArea from '../../../dist/scrollArea.js';
```

Comment: i've updated your question's title so that it's a real question, please adjust it a bit if you like

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't waste time understanding the build process of every library maintainer out there. Instead, iterate upon your own, and see what makes sense. I'd create my own component or use an existing one that require the scrollable functionality, and implement the component I imported from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollbar) as such: `import ScrollArea from 'react-scrollbar'`. I'd follow [this pattern](https://github.com/souhe/reactScrollbar/blob/master/examples/basic/js/app.jsx) for doing so.

Regarding styling, you have several ways of doing it and this is only dependent on how *you* handle styling in your project. If you're already compiling LESS files, then merge the LESS file from the library into the LESS file your project-specific component is going to use. If you're not, just copy/paste the CSS somewhere, or require it in your code, if you use webpack and `style-loader` for example.